# Main class not found when adding jar to classPath

Tags: java, maven

I'm not really a developper but I need a tool and I'm willing to improve myself .. be kind with my code please ..

I'm trying to write a jar tool, but whenever I'm packaging it in a jar with Maven, my main class is never found .. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Here is my java code

```
package com.github.keydam.addprometheuslistener;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
import picocli.CommandLine.Option;

@Command
public class addPrometheusListener implements Runnable {
    @Option(names = { "-f", "--file" }, required = true, description = "JMX file") 
    public static File jmxFile;

    public void run() {
        // Test de l'existence du fichier
        boolean jmxFileExists = jmxFile.exists();

        if (jmxFileExists) {
            // Positionnement de JMETER_HOME
            String jmeterHome = "C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Documents\\Outils\\Jmeter\\5.5";

            // Initialisation de Jmeter
            try {
                StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
                JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
                JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterHome + "/bin/jmeter.properties");
                SaveService.loadProperties();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            // Chargement du fichier
            try {
                HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(jmxFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error : file '" + jmxFile + "' does not exist");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int exitCode = new CommandLine(new addPrometheusListener()).execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode); 
    }
}
```

And here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <!--<packaging>jar</packaging>-->

  <groupId>com.github.keydam.addprometheuslistener</groupId>
  <artifactId>addPrometheusListener</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>addPrometheusListener</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <jmeter.version>5.5</jmeter.version>
    <jmeter.path>C:/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/Outils/Jmeter/5.5</jmeter.path>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
        <version>${jmeter.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${jmeter.path}/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
        <version>${jmeter.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${jmeter.path}/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_java.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
        <artifactId>jorphan</artifactId>
        <version>${jmeter.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${jmeter.path}/lib/jorphan.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.picocli</groupId>
        <artifactId>picocli</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.github.keydam.addprometheuslistener.addPrometheusListener</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Class-Path>${jmeter.path}</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.github.keydam.addprometheuslistener.addPrometheusListener</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Class-Path>${jmeter.path}/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar ${jmeter.path}/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_java.jar ${jmeter.path}/lib/jorphan.jar</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I dont need the Jmeter jar to be in the package because they will be available on the system this code might run ..
What am I missing or doing wrong ? My main class is never found when I try to execute my jar

Well I tried a lot of debug, and the only thing I noticed is when I comment the manifestEntries section I dont have this problem anymore, but I'm missing the Jmeter libraries .. which seems normal.

Comment: Why not just use the Jmeter supplied from maven central, and setting the scope as `provided` to not include it in the final build? Forcing maven to use local jarfiles basically breaks the entire purpose of maven.

Comment: If you are trying to execute a jar, apart setting permissions as executable as a file property  (not usually needed if another program executes the java.exe or java.bin or java) you need to edit the manifest.mf in theMETA-INF folder of the .jar file to specify the Main-Class:     see the SDK docs  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html     and   how to in the java tutorial   (program entry point) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html